# Python: How to concatenate Variables and Array

Tags: python

Example I have attributes as below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [3,2,1]
r1 = 5
r2 = 6
```

How do I get:

```
foo = [1,2,3,3,2,1,5,6]
```

Comment: `foo = a + b + [r1] + [r2]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - append vs. extend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/python-append-vs-extend)

Answer (score 2):

@falsetru
As simple as:

```
foo = a + b + [r1, r2]
```

Comment: You can't add an `int` to a `list`.

Comment: Why don't you do `a + b + [r1, r2]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
def combine(*args):
    result = []
    for arg in args:
        if type(arg) is int:
            result.append(arg)
        elif type(arg) is list:
            result += arg
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many options:

How @falsetru said:

`foo = a + b + [r1] + [r2]`

Or:

```
foot = []
foot.extend(a)
foot.extend(b)
foot.append(r1)
foot.append(r2)
```

Or:

```
foot = []
foot.extend(a)
foot.extend(b)
foot.extend([r1])
foot.extend([r2])
```

Or:

```
foot = []
foot.extend(a + b + [r1] + [r2])
```

You can know more about the lists here: [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)